# Modifying an entire directory to use the camelCase naming convention

Tags: javascript, typescript, refactoring, naming-conventions, code-formatting

I have a TypeScript project that has named variables, functions, etc using the `snake_case` convention. I'd like to adhere to the widely accepted JavaScript naming guidelines (i.e. `camelCase`) but I'm having trouble coming up with a solution for implementing this across my codebase.

I read that [ESLint does not plan to include a `--fix` option for the `camelCase` rule](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7530#issuecomment-266543547), so I searched a bit more and stumbled upon [`jscodeshift`](https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift). I'm wondering if a codemod is the appropriate way to solve this problem. If so, I'd appreciate some tips -- I've never written one before.

If anybody has any other ideas, I'd be glad to hear them.

Comment: since it is TypeScript, did you apply refactor to every variable/function definition? it should do the trick.

Comment: @CarlosBarcelona What do you mean?

Comment: your code editor should identify the code and you could apply refactor to the method. The code editor will search and replace safely.

Comment: @CarlosBarcelona That's not what I'm asking for.